# AppSync Queries/Mutations killed in background iOS

Tags: ios, swift, networking, aws-appsync

In my iOS app, I have a shared networking layer that performs AppSync queries and mutations. However, when I make a request, put the app into the background, and then back into the foreground, I always get an error.

```
Task <73E2850C-3264-4177-8027-011FDF3FB236>.<13> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x2828b03c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <73E2850C-3264-4177-8027-011FDF3FB236>.<13>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <73E2850C-3264-4177-8027-011FDF3FB236>.<13>"

NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://<url>/graphql, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://<url>/graphql, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

The request obviously continues on our server but the user is shown an error. What is the best way to handle this? Should I wrap every query/mutation with a `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask/UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask`? Or is there a better way to handle this specifically for AppSync.